# Square parentheses in diagxy

Tags: xy-pic

I am having problems with the `diagxy` package. Namely, texmaker does not want to compile the following code

```
\begin{document}
\[ 
\bfig
\Square(600,0)[[\Delta,\ y\of A[f/\bar{x}]] `[\Gamma,\ x\of A]`\Delta`  \Gamma;(f,\ y)`\pi_{A[f/\bar{x}]}`\pi_{A}`f]
\efig
\]
\end{document}
```

I think the problem is basically given by the square parentheses `[` and `]` used inside `\Square`. Indeed, if I take them out, everything works well. I have also tried to replace `[` with `\left[` and `]` with `\right]`, but this does not work either. Is there a way to circumvent the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a full document, not just the body. Where can we find `diagxy`? I don't know this package -- ah, it's `\input{diagxy}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `\of` is, so I gave it an arbitrary definition.

Your diagnosis is correct: LaTeX is confused about the closing `]` of the optional argument. The best is to define a proper macro for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\input{diagxy}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bracket}{[}{]}

\newcommand{\of}{???} % ???

\begin{document}
\[
\bfig
\Square(600,0)[
  \bracket{\Delta,\ y\of A\bracket{f/\bar{x}}} `\bracket{\Gamma,\ x\of A}`\Delta`
  \Gamma;(f,\ y)`\pi_{A\bracket{f/\bar{x}}}`\pi_{A}`f]
\efig
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to see how it's realized in `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\of}{???}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bracket}{[}{]}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=4em]
\bracket{\Delta, y\of A\bracket{f/\bar{x}}}
\arrow[r,"{(f, y})"]
\arrow[d,swap,"\pi_{A\bracket{f/\bar{x}}}"] &
  \bracket{\Gamma, x\of A}
  \arrow[d,"\pi_{A}"]
\\
\Delta \arrow[r,"f" swap] & \Gamma
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works! I forgot about the macro \of, but that does not really matter, as you promptly showed. Thanks again!